# create vercel next-js image response with arabic text extra spaces

Tags: html, image, next.js, response, vercel

I am using vercel [vercel og playground](https://og-playground.vercel.app/) to create image response as open-graphImage but at using arabic language an extra space is add

```
<div
  style={{
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    fontSize: 32,
    fontWeight: 600,
  }}
>
  <svg
    width="75"
    viewBox="0 0 75 65"
    fill="#000"
    style={{ margin: '0 75px' }}
  >
    <path d="M37.59.25l36.95 64H.64l36.95-64z"></path>
  </svg>
  <div style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>ما هي العقيدة</div>
</div>
```

[image: screen shot of the problem]